# how to know the presence of the values of an array in another array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am looking for a function in numpy or another package. Indeed, I have two arrays A and B, I would like to have a function where I could get an array "C" with the same length as A but filled with True and False : where it indicates the presence of a value of B in A ?

I have written some code down below to explain what I want :)

```
A = np.array(range(0,10))
print(A)
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]

B = np.array([4,8])
print(B)
[4 8]
```

C = [False False  False  False  True False  False  False  True False]

Thank you so much

Adrien

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for [`np.in1d`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html), which does the following:

> Test whether each element of a 1-D array is also present in a second array.
> Returns a boolean array the same length as ar1 that is True where an element of ar1 is in ar2 and False otherwise.

Or [`np.isin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html#numpy.isin) which does the same but keeps the dimensions of your original array (in your case, both are the same because A is already a flat array)

```
In [9]: np.in1d(A,B)
Out[9]: 
array([False, False, False, False,  True, False, False, False,  True,
       False])

In [10]: np.isin(A,B)
Out[10]: 
array([False, False, False, False,  True, False, False, False,  True,
       False])
```

Comment: It is exactly what  I was looking for !! Thank you so much